# How can I send a combination of three keys with advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I would like to send three keys at the same time using Advanced Scripting in a voice command, namely  the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. How can I achieve that?

I know that for sending the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> I can use `SendKeys "^2"` (read in this [guide](http://www.exaq.com/DNS/QR10/ScriptingReference.html#VB-SendKeys)).

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

---

In fact, that root of the issue is that I can't find a way to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> in Advanced Scripting, like I would do using a step-by-step command:

[image]

Comment: From that reference are you able to use the `Combination Keys` section and send ``^(`2)``?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately using  SendKeys "^(12)" does Ctrl + 1, then Ctrl + 2, not Ctrl + 1 + 2 at the same time.

Comment: And just the normal ``{Ctrl}+`+2`` or ``^+`+2`` doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't work either. Btw `{Ctrl}` is for SendDragonKeys, `^` for SendKeys ( [What is the difference between the commands SendKeys, SendSystemKeys or SendDragonKeys?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24110929/395857)).

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-send-a-combination-of-three-keys-with-advanced-scripting