# What is the difference between the commands SendKeys, SendSystemKeys or SendDragonKeys?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

When writing a voice command using Advanced Scripting, I can send the key using `SendKeys`, `SendSystemKeys` or `SendDragonKeys`. What's the difference between those three commands?

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongst other differences, SendKeys, SendSystemKeys or SendDragonKeys use different key names:

[image]

[image]

[image]