# How can I send a tilde in advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I want to send a tilde in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting. I tried `SendKeys "~"`, but `~` is replaced by a <kbd>ENTER</kbd> keystroke, as [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110929/395857).

Example:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "source ~/.bash_profile"
End Sub
```

[image]

How can I send a tilde in advanced scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{}` as escape characters, e.g., `SendKeys "{~}"`. By the same token, you would use `SendKeys "{+}"`, `SendKeys "{^}"`, and `SendKeys "{%}"`, to send a plus sign, a caret, and a percentage sign, respectively.

As a result, your example becomes:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "source {~}/.bash_profile"
End Sub
```