# How can I send a right windows key with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

Tags: windows, keyboard, naturallyspeaking, windows-key

How can I send a right windows key with Dragon NaturallySpeaking's advanced scripting?

[image]

Looking at  [What is the difference between the commands SendKeys, SendSystemKeys or SendDragonKeys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24110929/395857) it doesn't seem possible with `SendKeys`, `SendSystemKeys` or `SendDragonKeys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the  right windows key:

```
' From https://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=3&threadid=3032
' Author: monkey8
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
Const VK_RWIN = 92
Sub Main
keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,0,0)
'if you want to send a key while holding down the Windows key then insert the code here
keybd_event(VK_RWIN,0,2,0)
End Sub
```

Pressing the left windows key:

```
' From https://knowbrainer.com/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=3&threadid=3032
' Author: monkey8
' Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As _
Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
Const VK_LWIN = 91
Sub Main
keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,0,0)
'if you want to send a key while holding down the Windows key then insert the code here
keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,2,0)
End Sub
```

Useful reference for the keyboard codes:  [List of Virtual Key Codes](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170628014411/http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html))

Answer (score 1):

Note the `Declare` stuff has to be ABOVE the `Sub Main` in your script.  Then this is what it will look like if you're using a modifier key:

```
Declare Function keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long, bScan As Long, ByVal Flag As Long, ByVal exInfo As Long) As Long
Const VK_LWIN = 91

Sub Main

keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,0,0)
SendSystemKeys "{Right}"
keybd_event(VK_LWIN,0,2,0)
```